# Are systemd directive names case sensitive?

Tags: systemd, case-sensitivity

systemd directives used in the unit files are in [the documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.directives.html) listed using mixed case like `UMask` or `AccuracySec`. Is it actually necessary to follow this exact wording, or is it just good practice, but the parsing is actually case insensitive? I could not find anything neither in [the documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/index.html) nor in [the source code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd).

To be more specific. This is an example Drop-In overriding the `UMask` value:

```
[Service]
UMask=0027
```

Would the `UMask` directive be correctly read if written with different case?

```
[Service]
umask=0027
```

Using `UMask` as an example, because as far as I know the systemd directive name is the only place where the term is capitalized like this. The UNIX command name is `umask` in all lowercase, which is not surprising. Even the systemd [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#UMask=) spells the term when it’s not a command name in all lowercase.

> … The per-user **umask** may also be set via …

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the directive names **are case sensitive**.

tl;dr

You can empirically check this by setting the value and then running `systemctl show` to list all directives set for the unit.

The default state without any drop-ins with a default umask value:

```bsh
$ systemctl show sshd
…
UMask=0022
…
```

If you set the value correctly by a Drop-In, the value changes:

```bsh
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
UMask=0027
```

```bsh
$ systemctl show sshd
…
UMask=0027
…
```

But if you use incorrect letter case in the directive name, the value is not picked:

```bsh
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
umask=0027
```

```bsh
$ systemctl show sshd
…
UMask=0022
…
```

You can use `| grep -i umask` to see the processed directives regardless of the case:

```bsh
$ systemctl show sshd | grep -i umask
UMask=0022
```

Don’t forget to run `systemctl daemon-reload` after any change to the unit files when experimenting.