# How do I disable the "cache" for systemd-resolved?

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved

I am using another dns resolver, `blocky` and using it with `systemd-resolved`.  `blocky` already has features like caching and prefetching. So I don't want `systemd-resolved` running a cache and messing with `blocky`'s prefetching. But how do I disable the "cache" for systemd-resolved?

Config file:

`/etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/dns.conf`

```
[Resolve]
#blocky
DNS=127.0.0.10

DNSSEC=yes

# how to disable cache?
cache=no 

FallbackDNS=84.200.69.80 8.8.8.8 2001:1608:10:25::9249:d69b 2001:4860:4860::8844

Domains=~.
```

Setting `cache=no` has no effect. `systemd-resolved` statistics:

```
❯ systemd-resolve --statistics
DNSSEC supported by current servers: yes

Transactions              
Current Transactions: 2
  Total Transactions: 4008
                          
Cache                     
  Current Cache Size: 189
          Cache Hits: 1044
        Cache Misses: 3072
                          
DNSSEC Verdicts           
              Secure: 230
            Insecure: 410
               Bogus: 731
       Indeterminate: 0
```

PS: I could directly use `blocky` but `systemd-resolved` handles DNS during various network scenarios better.

Comment: duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687342/are-systemd-directive-names-case-sensitive .  also, why not just disable systemd-resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is 'Cache', not cache. systemd configuration is case-sensitive.